# Excel sum one column based on another

Tags: excel-formula

I have data that is divided into columns as follows:

```
Runs    RunsAfter   Switch     New
 0          2          1
 0          2          0
 1          2          0
 0          1          0
 1          1          0
 0          0          0
 0          0          0
 0          0          1
 0          1          0 
 1          1          0
 0          0          0
```

I want excel to sum the Runs column by taking each cell and summing down the remainder of the column until there is a 1 in the Switch column. It should then start calculating again until another Switch. All of this output should be put in the New column. The result should look like the RunsAfter column, which I am currently calculating by hand. I would keep doing this, but the dataset is going to get too big to continue doing this by hand.

I've checked for questions similar to this, but haven't been able to find quite what I'm looking for. If I've missed an answer elsewhere, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, I think you want to use a combination of the match formula to find the next "switch" and the indirect formula to define the range to sum.  I can't think of a simple way to do this.

This is assuming that your headers are in row 1 and your columns are Runs (A), RunsAfter (B), Switch (C), and results in D.  I've used 100 for your last row, but you will need to change that if you have more rows.  This is what I did in D2:

To find the next row for which Switch is 1:
    MATCH(1,C3:$C$100,0)+ROW()

I also included iferror to make it not break for rows after the last switch:
    IFERROR(MATCH(1,C3:$C$100,0)+ROW()-1,100)

I included this as part of the indirect formula to tell it what range to sum up:

```
D2=SUM( INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A$"&IFERROR(MATCH(1,C3:$C$100,0)+ROW()-1,100)))
```

So for D2, it's summing from A2 to the row before the next switch, in this case row 8.  You should be able to drag it down from D2 with those anchors.